# Haskell Chart Package: What is a "pick function"?

Tags: haskell, charts

I've been reading the source code of the [Haskell Chart package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart) as I find the charts it creates are very good. But I'm stumped on how it works.

In particular, there is a [type `PickFn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-1.2.2/docs/src/Graphics-Rendering-Chart-Renderable.html#PickFn) that is used by the `render` function:

```
type PickFn a = Point -> Maybe a

data Renderable a = Renderable {
   minsize :: ChartBackend RectSize,
   render  :: RectSize -> ChartBackend (PickFn a)
}

class ToRenderable a where
  toRenderable :: a -> Renderable ()
```

Commentary for `PickFn` is "*A function that maps a point in device coordinates to some value.*" which unfortunately doesn't mean anything to me.

My ultimate goal is to be able to follow the code to learn how it draws its charts, but I'd like to start with "what is a pick function" so that I can at least understand the types.

Comment: It might be informative to figure out what the type of `Renderable a`'s `render` function is. You can do so by substituting the definition of `PickFn` into it.

Comment: I believe `ChartBackend` is a monad that wraps an external library that actually does the rendering.

Answer (score 2):

The pick function is a convenience to the client of the Chart library - it lets you map back from a point in the resulting image to the thing (that's the `Maybe a`) at that position.

For example, [Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Layout.layoutToRenderable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Chart-1.2.2/docs/Graphics-Rendering-Chart-Layout.html#v%3alayoutToRenderable) returns a `Renderable (LayoutPick x y y)` so that you can map back from a point in the picture back to a specific component of the layout - its legend, an axis title, the plot area, etc.